# C# save to SQLite from new form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, listview

I have a small project in SQLite. I show all of examples in ListViewlike this:

```
SQLiteConnection oSQLiteConnection =
                new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.s3db");
            SQLiteCommand oCommand = oSQLiteConnection.CreateCommand();
            oCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PERSONS";
            m_oDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(oCommand.CommandText,
                oSQLiteConnection);
            SQLiteCommandBuilder oCommandBuilder =
                new SQLiteCommandBuilder(m_oDataAdapter);
            m_oDataSet = new DataSet();
            m_oDataAdapter.Fill(m_oDataSet);
            m_oDataTable = m_oDataSet.Tables[0];
            lstItems.DataContext = m_oDataTable.DefaultView;
```

I also have a button wchich open new form with field like name, username and I want to click save (in that new open form) and save a new row to my database and update this view. How can I do that? In my "min" viewI can do ststaic like this

```
DataRow oDataRow = m_oDataTable.NewRow();
oDataRow[1] = "Name";
oDataRow[2] = "Username";
m_oDataTable.Rows.Add(oDataRow);
m_oDataAdapter.Update(m_oDataSet);
```

How to save this from a new form? I can't do that :(

Answer (score 0):

Look hire 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/save-delete-search-and-update-record-in-ado-net/

I like to use entity framework

```
 using (var context = new Db())
        {
            try
            {
               ...
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```